# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't update arrayadapter items

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

The following App flow shows what I expected ("Alfa" in the autocomplete list):

Open App -> click on button -> tap on autocomplete field -> type "al"

But this one fails (and if I type "br", "Bravo" is still in the list):

Open App -> tap on autocomplete field -> type anything and then delete it -> click on button -> tap on autocomplete field -> type "al"

Why the list is not updated in the second sequence?

```
public class DisplayFragment extends Fragment {

 AutoCompleteTextView autoCTVShop;
 Button buttonSend;

 String[] names= {"Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Foxtrot"};
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display, container, false);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    autoCTVShop = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewShop);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    autoCTVShop.setAdapter(adapter);
    buttonSend = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //The following two lines don't work as I expected
            names[0]="Alfa";
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }); 
 }


 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
}
```

fragment_display.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewShop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally the `ArrayAdapter` uses 2 lists to store and handle the items. Initially your passed in items are stored and handled through a list named `mObjects`. Any changes to your outside `names` object would be reflected in the `mObjects` list as well.

As soon as you start filtering, a second list, named `mOriginalValues` is created. During the filtering flow, `mObjects` is going to be used as the "current values" container, while `mOriginalValues` is used as a "reset to and re-filter" container. Changing the `names` values will have no influence anymore. You could change the adapter values directly (adapter.insert(...), adapter.remove(...) - it will modify `mOriginalValues`) or recreate the adapter

Comment: I debug the code and see this thing. is it possible that main list as it is after type or clearing AutoCompleteTextview? because first time when I type "a" then three items are displayed and clear the first item value and second time I type "a" then it show only one item in the drop down :(

Comment: I got the solution after 2 days of R&D. I have done like store the main list in one another `temp` list and once user select the item reset that `temp` list again to `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is case sensitive. Try Al... that might be it. Also it could be because you are replacing names. I am not certain but when you pass through names it could be setting it to an instance var that won't update at the same time. so you will need to re-pass through the array.

Comment: Thanks WIll but as I said, the first sequence of steps shows the correct name (Alfa). The question is why the second sequence of steps doesn't show the same.